# list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] what is the difference between list.clear() and if i declare list = [ ]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
list.clear()
print(list)

O/P : [ ]
```

---

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
list=[]
print(list)
O/P : [ ]
```

Both the case I am getting same output. So what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4):

`clear()` will keep the same reference, but empty the list. `[]` creates a new list and assigns it to the variable.

Example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> a.clear()
>>> a is b
True
>>> a = []
>>> a is b
False
```

Note that `a` and `b` are still the same object after the clear, but different objects after you assign a new list to a.

Comment: It is also instructive to add `print(a)` and `print(b)` in appropriate locations.